# May not have learned this correctly

Tags: format, printf

I want my answer to read

```
                1 2 3
Matrix A =      1 2 3
                1 2 3
```

but it reads

```
Matrix A = 
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

can anyone tell me how I should go about trying to format?

```
public static void IO(int[][] a, int[][] b)
   {
      int i;

      int j;

      System.out.print("Please Enter the Numbers for Matrix A: ");

      for(i=0;i<3;i++)

         for(j=0;j<3;j++)

            a[i][j]=scan.nextInt();

      System.out.println();

      System.out.print("Please Enter The Numbers for Matrix B: ");

      for(i=0;i<3;i++)

         for(j=0;j<3;j++)

            b[i][j]=scan.nextInt();

      System.out.printf("%-1s%n", "Matrix A = ");

      for(i=0;i<3;i++)
      {
         for(j=0;j<3;j++)
         {
            System.out.printf("%5d", a[i][j]);
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
      System.out.printf("%-1s%n", "Matrix B = ");


      for(i=0;i<3;i++)
      {
         for(j=0;j<3;j++)
         {
            System.out.printf("%5d", b[i][j]);
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
```

I know this may seem very simple to some but I've only been programming for a semester now. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of:

```
  System.out.printf("%-1s%n", "Matrix A = ");
```

and change your loop to:

```
  for(i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
     for(j=0;j<3;j++)
     {
        if(j == 1)
            line_prefix = "Matrix A = ";
        else
            line_prefix = " ";
        System.out.printf("%12.12s%5d", lineprefix, a[i][j]);
     }
     System.out.println();
  }
```